# Javascript: cross browser solution for selecting all text inside a textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm after the following functionality:

- user clicks on or tabs into a textbox
- all text in the textbox is selected, unless the textbox already had focus, in which case the default clicking/selecting functionality should occur

Is this possible?

---

**This works in Firefox 5**

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function () {
    this.select();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/13/

Chrome and IE8 selects all the text for only a split second

---

**This works* in Chrome**

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('click', function () {
    this.select();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/12/

Firefox and IE8 selects all text but upon subsequent clicking, the text remains selected.

*kind of works, after textbox has focus, clicking on it alternates between selecting all text and being able to click where the blinking caret goes. This is probably acceptable.

Comment: I haven't tested it out, but does programatically selecting all of the text cause it to scroll to the top/beginning or bottom/end of the field the same way that it does when the user selects by pressing ctrl-A (assuming there is enough text entered to be able to scroll, obviously)? If so I'd try to avoid doing it on a mouse click event where the user was probably trying to click on the point where they want to start typing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just delay it by a millisecond with `setTimeout`:

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function() {
    var inp = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        inp.select();
    }, 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/14/

What's happening is some other browser event is setting the selection after you've selected the text.  So, by waiting a millisecond, you let all the browser events finish, and then select the text.  Nothing will undo it now.

Comment: Legend. All other answers still had the same problems with cross browser compatibility. Do you know what the other event is that would be causing this?

Comment: @ajbeaven I'd try an event.preventDefualt() it must be that your event is being overriden by the default (that selects nothing):  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Your answer fixed the problem, adding `preventDefault` and `return false` like other answers suggested didn't help.

Comment: @James try clicking twice on a textbox in firefox or IE8. Once anywhere on the textbox to select all text, and then again to try and move the caret to a position in the text. The second click re-selects all the text and doesn't position the caret.

Comment: hmm, seem to be having another problem with this approach. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869717/google-chrome-infinite-loops-and-selecting-text

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

to your function (the first one). That may fix the other browsers.

Also, add `event` to the function sig:

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function (event) {
```

Comment: try clicking twice on a textbox in firefox or IE8. Once anywhere on the textbox to select all text, and then again to try and move the caret to a position in the text. The second click re-selects all the text and doesn't position the caret.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember to do a `return false; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault()` like so:

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('click', function (event) {
    this.select();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7rYLV/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery then you can do something like;

```
$("#myInputField").focus(function(){
    // Select input field contents
    this.select();
});

// Add this behavior to all text fields
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
    // Select field contents
    this.select();
});
```

Taken from [HERE](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/select-text-in-input-box-on-user-select.html)