# jQuery Focus Event Keeps Alert Box in Infinite Loop (Chrome)

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know why displaying a simple alert box in the following `focus()` event handler never stops? I also tried `focusin()` with the same result. Is the event being fired multiple times in a loop? ***I am running in Chrome***

```js
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {  // Also tried focusin(..)
  alert('Focus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input:
<input type="text" id="myinput"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way. you define a global variable first. then you can act on it. Reason : 
For the reason that it is always chosen. When you press the OK button on the alertbox, it becomes input focus again. Therefore it enters into a continuous loop.

```js
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {  // Also tried focusin(..)
  alert('focus');
  $(this).blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input:
<input type="text" id="myinput"/>
```

Also : [Javascript: cross browser solution for selecting all text inside a textbox on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852495/javascript-cross-browser-solution-for-selecting-all-text-inside-a-textbox-on-fo)

Comment: doesn't do it in Firefox. thanks for the explanation